# EU refunds law for purchases made before comming to the European Union

Tags: european-union

If someone makes a purchase outside EU and then migrates to the EU will the EU 2 year legal gaurantee apply to that purchased big or small thing for?What if the person travels to EU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The entity responsible that the goods are satisfactory is the seller. If you bought an item outside the EU, then the seller is not in the EU, and therefore not required to follow EU law.